# Do we need to use 'the' here?

Tags: determiners

In 'the novel navigates present-day US' do we need 'the' before 'present-day US' as we would usually before 'US'?

Comment: What comes next? It sounds like US is a noun here but are you sure?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need the "the" here - specifically for "the US". There are some countries and places which need an article in English:

- The US
- The Netherlands
- The Wirral

Whereas most don't:

- America
- Holland
- Liverpool

You could omit the "the" by saying

> The novel navigates present-day America.

Comment: Surely, "present-day America" also encompasses Canada, Mexico & Southern America, which is rather different from "the US" in the original article!

Comment: That's more rigorous yes! "The US" avoids ambiguity - though "America" and "The United States" are used synonymously in everyday speech (at least they are in British English, which I speak)

Comment: I too speak British English and agree with your comment about British usage - but I didn't know your nationality (or what 'type' of English you speak) when I wrote my comment.  Nevertheless, when specifying the area which "the novel navigates", I would have thought it important to distinguish between the country & the continent.

Comment: As in a comment under the question, *the* may not be needed depending on how the sentence finishes. For example: *The novel navigates present-day US landmarks*. It's not clear if we've been given a complete sentence, where *US* is a noun.

Comment: The complete sentence is 'The debut novel navigates present-day US with its police brutality, racial tension and immigrant angst', so 'US' is being used as a noun. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While it's common to add the "the" to "US" and some other places, it's not required.

I think it's more important to add periods, like so:

U.S.

This differentiates between the country and an emphasized "us."